# Magento 2, why data-mage-init validation not working when I use knockout component

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, form-validation

I have a phtml file with a form that used data-mage-init

```
<form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

and then I initialize a knockout component at the bottom of the page

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "mycomponent": {
                        "component": "Company_Module/js/mycomponent"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

For some reason the validation only works when I remove the "x-magento-init" script at the bottom. I had to make the validation work by calling click using knockoutjs on the button and validating in the component
When the "x-magento-init" script is on the page, the submit call on the validation never seems to happen. I can't figure out why? Anyone know?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use validation in UI component you need to use `data-bind="mageInit: {'validation': {}}"` instead of `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'`.

So you form tag should looks like this:

`<form data-bind="mageInit: {'validation': {}}" class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
</form>`

Comment: This answer should be accepted.

Comment: Can't believe this isn't documented better in the Dev Docs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you so much it is really awesome. I have spent 2 days on this but was not been able to find a solution.